# On the number of MC simulation runs required to find computational complexity

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

This is not related to the theoretical methods (read Big $O$) of determining complexity expressions. Suppose there is input variable $x$ and output variable $y$ and 10 other variables that affect the output but are kept fixed. So I vary $x$ over 100 values and record corresponding $x,y$. This is one MC run. Then I can find the relationship between $x$ and $y$ by poly-fitting, log-log analysis etc. Then I conclude something like $y=cx,y=x^c,y=c^x$.

Now we can run 2-3 more simulations by changing the 10 variables and collecting the $x-y$ data. And I may find conclusions for them also.

My question is how many such situations we have to run to say with confidence that the relationship between the variables in the context of the simulator used has been established?

Is that dependent on the fact that the relationship is linear, polynomial or exponential? For example, if the relationship is linear then is one MC run enough to establish the exact math expression for the relationship.

Comment: I don't understand where the stochasticity is, so I cannot help you. You must explain the role of the Monte Carlo aspect of the computation (i.e. why you do not simply fit a data set).

Comment: @Ian So I don't assume stochasticity meaning if those 10 variables are fixed and I run the simulator 100 times for say x=1.34, I will always get the same y=5.4

Comment: @Ian but it would interesting to answer the stochastic version of the problem also by extendign the above as required.

Comment: So what you really want to do has nothing to do with stochasticity, it is just part of how you compute the $y$ but can be thought of as a black box. In the end you are interested in curve fitting. Error estimation for curve fitting is a subtle beast because it relies on assumptions about how nice the underlying curve is.

Comment: Also, I am not trying to be rude. I'm just trying to reduce the problem to its core, stripping away details that can be, at least for the purposes of the answerer, treated as black boxes. (This is sort of like the "XY problem": https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem though it is really more like the notion of a minimal working example from Stack Overflow etc.)

Comment: @Ian I completely agree!